# libcurl.so no version information available

Tags: linux, curl, libcurl

I'm using Debian, when I try to use Curl I have this error :

```
curl: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by curl)
cURL error 1: Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I'd tried to remove and install **curl and openssl** but nothing change.
Thank's for your help.

Comment: Do you have multiple version of curl installed?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/696631/libcurl-so-4-no-version-information-available